# Firebase exception:Object Does Not Exist

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I was uploading a image to Firebase Storage and this error keeps coming

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>       Object does not exist at location.
>        Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
>   "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
>       java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}

This is my code:

```
StorageReference postimage_path=firebaseStorage.child("Post Image").child(random+".jpg");

postimage_path.putFile(newposturi);
postimage_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful())
        {

            Uri download_url=task.getResult();
            Map<String,String> postmap=new HashMap<>();
            postmap.put("download url",download_url.toString());
            postmap.put("Description",post);
            postmap.put("user_id",currentuser);
            postmap.put("timestamp",""+FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
            postfirestore.collection("Posts").add(postmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else{
                    String error=task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error while Posting :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                    newpostprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that there's no object in storage with the path you're building like this:

```
StorageReference postimage_path=firebaseStorage.child("Post Image").child(random+".jpg");
```

The missing object is causing `getDownloadUrl()` to fail.

You'll have to do some debugging to figure out what the path should be, and make sure the named object actually exists.

Comment: Image is getting posted at that storage path if its getting posted and is available in Firebase Storage why cant then DownloadUrl() get that object at the same path

Comment: If your code isn't waiting for the upload to complete, then the download URL won't be available until it does.

Comment: Okayy, I get it but how do I fix it....... and another weird thing is that I used the same code in another activity and it was working,the image was being posted and the download Url was also generated if you wanna see I'll show you that piece of code as well but I did the exact same thing and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your firebase permissions on storage. It should have read/write permission. Also check the firebase rules.

Other important thing is,

Runtime permissions added in marshmallow.
Enable storage permissions on android device. android marshmallow+ you have to allow the permissions for app.

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
      allow read : if true;
    }
  }
}
This is the rules that I gave it still isnt debugging