Permission Denied Selecting an Image
I was trying to use Firebase Storage to change the Profile Image by selecting one form the device and uploading it, but when i click on the Select Image button i get an Error "Permission denied. Unable to select image. " Someone can help me thanks in advance.
package it.unich.s3221238.tesi;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 2;
    private static final int EDIT_PROFILE_REQUEST = 3;
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";

    private TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername;
    private ImageView profileImg;
    private Button selectImageButton, uploadImageButton, editProfile, homeButton;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private String currentUsername;
    private StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        profileName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        profileEmail = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileUsername = findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        profileImg = findViewById(R.id.profileImg);
        selectImageButton = findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);
        uploadImageButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadImageButton);
        editProfile = findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        homeButton = findViewById(R.id.homeButton);

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        showAllUserData();

        editProfile.setOnClickListener(v -> passUserData());
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());

        selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
            } else {
                openImagePicker();
            }
        });

        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (imageUri != null) {
                uploadImageToFirebase();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Please select an image first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showAllUserData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nameUser = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String emailUser = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        String usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        profileName.setText(nameUser);
        profileEmail.setText(emailUser);
        profileUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        currentUsername = usernameUser;

        loadProfileImage();  // Load the profile image if available
    }

    private void passUserData() {
        String userUsername = profileUsername.getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUserDatabase = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userUsername);

        checkUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    String nameFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String emailFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(userUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_PROFILE_REQUEST);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Database error: ", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private void openImagePicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            profileImg.setImageURI(imageUri); // Show the selected image immediately
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (requestCode == EDIT_PROFILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String updatedName = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String updatedEmail = data.getStringExtra("email");
            String updatedUsername = data.getStringExtra("username");

            profileName.setText(updatedName);
            profileEmail.setText(updatedEmail);
            profileUsername.setText(updatedUsername);
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebase() {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            String filePath = "profile_images/" + currentUsername + ".jpg";
            Log.d(TAG, "Uploading image to path: " + filePath);

            StorageReference profileImageRef = storageReference.child(filePath);

            profileImageRef.putFile(imageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                        Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this)
                                .load(uri)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.akwhitelogo)
                                .into(profileImg);
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }))
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Image upload failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Upload error: ", e);
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadProfileImage() {
        if (currentUsername != null) {
            String filePath = "profile_images/" + currentUsername + ".jpg";
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading image from path: " + filePath);

            StorageReference profileImageRef = storageReference.child(filePath);

            profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this)
                        .load(uri)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.akwhitelogo)
                        .into(profileImg);
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                profileImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.akwhitelogo);
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load profile image: ", e);
            });
        } else {
            profileImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.akwhitelogo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openImagePicker();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied. Unable to select image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

This is my Profile class, it shows no errors
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="it.unich.s3221238.tesi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.Light"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Workout"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ExerciseDetailActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PrivacyActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

    </application>
</manifest>

And this is the manifest.
This is the logcat error:
 StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                                    Object does not exist at location.
                                                                                                     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2024-08-05 00:37:28.761 10819-10855 StorageException        it.unich.s3221238.tesi               E  {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
                                                                                                    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:415)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:432)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:423)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:265)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:282)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.lambda$decorate$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-LimitedConcurrencyExecutor(LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.java:65)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2024-08-05 00:37:28.794 10819-10819 WindowOnBackDispatcher  it.unich.s3221238.tesi               W  sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=ImeCallback=ImeOnBackInvokedCallback@236402277 Callback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@5213cd
2024-08-05 00:37:28.911 10819-10819 ProfileActivity         it.unich.s3221238.tesi               E  Failed to load profile image: 
                                                                                                    com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location.
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.completeTask(NetworkRequest.java:509)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:85)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.lambda$decorate$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-LimitedConcurrencyExecutor(LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.java:65)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:415)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:432)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:423)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:265)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:282)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.lambda$decorate$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-LimitedConcurrencyExecutor(LimitedConcurrencyExecutor.java:65) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.LimitedConcurrencyExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 

I'm new to Firebase thanks for your patience.

What is the exact line of code that throws that error?

Android Studio non mi dà errori di codice, ma quando eseguo l'app e clicco su Seleziona un'immagine ottengo "autorizzazione negata", ho aggiornato le regole di archiviazione, ma non so cosa mi sto perdendo

Ensure that your Firebase Storage rules allow read and write access. During development, you can set permissive rules like this:
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
      }
   }
}

Note: This is not recommended for production. Make sure to set proper rules for your use case.

Still same error. that's the error i have in the log cat: https://pastebin.com/dZFWy8Hw

SImilar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400121/firebase-exceptionobject-does-not-exist
